# Connect bone to leg

Tags: rigging, armature

I downloaded Mr. Elephant from https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/
And now I try to animate the mouse.

First I selected the left leg and the bone "Bone.014" and with ctrl+p "parent to bone". but when I rotate the bone now the whole leg rotates. But I just want the foot to move a little bit.
Before rotation:
[image: Before rotation]
After rotation:
[image: After rotation]

Answer (score 0):

This procedure assign a  direct parenting of an entire object (the whole leg) to a bone, so the behaviour is what is expected. You should choose "with automatic weights" option instead, so that every vertex of the leg gets a weighted binding relatively to its closer deforming bones.